# subquery select when group by is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery

I've got a query I cannot figure out.

```
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(bar.id)
  FROM bar
  WHERE foo.some_id = bar.some_id
  ) AS num_bar
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY some_id
```

if foo looks like this:

```
ID|some_id
----------
1 |NULL
2 |apple
3 |orange
```

and bar looks like this

```
ID|some_id
----------
1 |NULL
2 |apple
3 |orange
4 |NULL
5 |apple
6 |orange
```

I expect it to return:

```
num_bar
-------
2
2
2
```

howerver, the count on the NULL grouping returns 0 each time.

What is the proper way to account for this WHERE clause when the group by is NULL?

Answer (score 1):

SQL aggregate functions and comparisons may ignore NULL values in their computation

What you might want to do is to give it a value and then interpret nulls accordingly. So in the below query, you are asking the query to interpret null values as -1.

```
SELECT (
 SELECT COUNT(bar.id)
 FROM bar
 WHERE isnull(foo.some_id, -1) = isnull(bar.some_id,-1)
) AS num_bar
FROM foo
GROUP BY isnull(some_id,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to count the `some_id` present in `bar` table along with `NULL's`.

Don't use `some_id` in `count` aggregate like `count(some_id)`. It will ignore the `NULL` values and return always zero when some_id is `NULL`.

Try this way

```
SELECT F.some_id,
       Count(1) AS count_someid
FROM   foo F
       INNER JOIN bar B
               ON F.some_id = B.some_id
                   OR ( F.some_id IS NULL AND B.some_id IS NULL ) -- To join NULL records
GROUP  BY F.some_id
```

`NULL's` present in `some_id` will also be grouped separately and counted

Answer (score 0):

Just a better way with the same logic as Nagendra Kakarla

```
SELECT  F.some_id ,COUNT(1) AS count_someid
FROM FOO F
INNER JOIN BAR B ON ISNULL(F.some_id,'#') = ISNULL(B.some_id,'#')
GROUP BY F.some_id
```

And you will get the result like

```
+---------+--------------+
| some_id | count_someid |
+---------+--------------+
| NULL    |            2 |
| apple   |            2 |
| orange  |            2 |
+---------+--------------+
```